# Construct BCG Matrix in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with Market share and Market growth for a particular products

```
     df
     Product          Market Share         Market Growth
       A                   15%                  23%
       B                   14%                   15%
       C                   20%                  58%
       D                   89%                   90%
```

and so on

Can we build a BCG matric showing market share in x axis and market growth in y axis. ALso I need the name of the Products to be names near the coordinates. Like (15,23) A, (14,15) B etc....

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot)

df %>%
ggplot(aes(x = 'Market Share', y = 'Market Growth', color = 'Product')) + geom_point() + geom_label(aes(label = Product))
```

This will do the trick! Additionally consult the [ggplot cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ggplot2-cheatsheet.pdf) for any further questions about formatting the plot.